# Finding user total votes recieved on posts by other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm using this gem for comments: https://github.com/lml/commontator

Which is setup to easily plug into this gem to vote on the comments: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

I'm using rails 4 btw, which is compatible with both gems.

In my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  acts_as_commentator
  has_many :comments
end
```

In my Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Everything seems to be working fine. But when trying to calculate a users total votes (the total votes received on all comments by the user) (karma)

```
<%= @user.votes.count %>
```

I get this error

```
undefined method `votes' for #<User:0x0000010dbf23a0>
```

So I tried this:

```
<%= @user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.inject(:+) %>
```

Which resulted in another error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: commontator_comments.commontator_id: SELECT "commontator_comments".* FROM "commontator_comments"  WHERE "commontator_comments"."commontator_id" = ? AND "commontator_comments"."commontator_type" = ?
```

I've tried:

```
@user.find_voted_items.count
```

and

```
@user.get_voted(Comment).count ?
```

and

```
@user.comments.collect{|c| c.votes.size}.inject(:+)
```

Nothing seems to work. I'm guessing it has to do with the way the commontator gem is handling the proxy associations relationship. How do I render the total number of votes received on all comments by a particular user? Any help is very much appreciated!

Edit: I did run all the migrations.

Comment: did you run the migrations?

Comment: Yup! I should have mentioned that!

Comment: What do you get with '@user.find_voted_items.count'?

Comment: That does not give me an error, but gives me the number of items that particular user has voted on, not the number of votes he has received on all of his comments.

Comment: In the commontator gem page, there's a section that describes how to integrate with acts_as_votable. Did you check that part? https://github.com/lml/commontator#voting. It seems that you have to add that setting, and then restart your app.

Comment: Yup, I set config.can_vote_on_comments = true in the initializer and restarted the app.

Comment: @KatieHeidmann I wonder if `has_many :comments` in the user model is causing all of this. When you include acts_as_commentator in your model, it already adds the relationship for you.

Comment: Hmm, what do you think I should have in my user model? Should I even have a comment model? Commentator already provides one.

Comment: Yes, it does provide it for you. You don't need a comment model. Also, quick question: did you run `rake commontator:install` when you added the gem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47518/discussion-between-h-man-and-katie-heidmann)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be counting votes on the comments? The User model `acts_as_voter` so, according to the docs on the gem, you can retrieve a list of the items a user has voted on with `find_voted_items`, but the Comment model is the one where you can count `votes` since that's what the user is voting on.

Edit, given the comments. At it's simplest, you probably need something similar to this:

```
sum = 0
@user.comments.each do |comment|
    sum += comment.votes.count
end
```

though you can probably make that a bit more eloquent with `inject` or even with Activerecord#sum on the votes field with a carefully constructed "where clause".

Comment: Yup, that's what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to render the sum score of all the comments that particular user has made. Sort of like their karma. What method should I use?

Comment: Well, I've only read the docs for the gem, but I would think you would want get the collection of comments a user has made and then iterate over them getting the score for each comment.

Comment: That gives me: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: commontator_comments.commontator_id: SELECT "commontator_comments".* FROM "commontator_comments"  WHERE "commontator_comments"."commontator_id" = ? AND "commontator_comments"."commontator_type" = ?

Comment: Okay - well, a little tricky to debug without seeing more of your code - what's in your schema.rb file, or if you have the project on github point us there....