# Routes on comments and votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-routes

I have two models that can be commented on, Books and Movies.

The comments are votable

In my routes file:

```
 resources :books, :path => '' do
    resources :comments do
      member do
    post :vote_up
  end
end
```

In my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    book.comments.create(new_comment_params) do |comment|
      comment.user = current_user
    end
    redirect_to book_path(book)
  end

  private

  def new_comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def book
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  end

  def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote_for(@comment = Comment.find(params[:id]))
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render :nothing => true, :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

In my view:

```
    <%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_book_comment_path(comment), 
:method => :post) %>
```

I keep on getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :book_id=>#<Comment id: 
3, body: "fantastic read!", book_id: 113, created_at: "2014-02-15 17:08:10", updated_at: 
"2014-02-15 17:08:10", user_id: 8>, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

This is the gem I am using for the voting: https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up

The comments can belong to either the books or movies, how do I set this up in the routes? Also, how do I set up the votes in the routes? (all the comments are votable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `rake routes`, you'll probably get a line in the output that reads like this:

```
vote_up_book_comment POST   /:book_id/comments/:id/vote_up(.:format) comments#vote_up
```

Pay special attention to this part — it's telling you what the `vote_up_book_comment_path` method expects as arguments:

```
/:book_id/comments/:id/vote_up(.:format)
```

Also, your error message is giving you a few hints:

```
No route matches ...
:id=>nil, :book_id=>#<Comment id: 3 ...
missing required keys: [:id]
```

The path helper expects an id (for the comment) and a book_id, and the order in which they are required is shown in `rake routes` (book_id first, then id).

So, in sum, you need to pass a `book` to `vote_up_book_comment_path`:

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_book_comment_path(@book, comment), :method => :post) %>
```

Comment: I'm now getting this error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: votes.voteable_id may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "votes" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)

Comment: Based on the [thumbs_up source code for `vote_for`](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voter.rb#L69), I'm guessing that means that `Comment.find(params[:id])` is returning `nil` within `CommentsController#vote_up` ... is `params[:id]` coming into the controller as expected?

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooo much! Your commenting system works perfectly. It turns out thumbs_up is a piece of crap, I ended up using the acts_as_votable gem, everything now works like a charm! :) Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hey Anthony! Can you take a look at this questions? I'm trying to add nested comments, should I just use the acts_as_commentable gem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963064/adding-threading-and-email-subscriptions-to-comments

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `member` in your routes, rails requires an id in the url. In `vote_up_book_comment_path(comment)` you supply a `book` id, but no `comment` id. It interpreted the `comment` argument as a book. To fix this, include a book object, changing `vote_up_book_comment_path(comment)` to `vote_up_book_comment_path(@book, comment)`. In your `new` method of your controller, include the `book` variable also so your view template can access it.

To set up comments in either the books or movies:

Because comments are separate from books or videos, you do not want to nest them under books. Instead, have comments be a separate route, and only have the route nested under books or videos when you are `new`ing or `edit`ing. That way you can have a hidden field in your view template that stores whether it's a book or a video, and then pass it along to the controller. Now the controller has the necessary information to know whether it's a `book_id` or a `movie_id`.

It would look something like this in the code:

```
resources :books do
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :edit]
end
```

You would do this for all resources you want. Finally for comments you would do something like this:

```
resources :comments, except: [:new, :edit]
```

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Now im getting: undefined method `vote_up_book_comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101c92cd0>:0x00000101c90e08> What path should I be using in my view?