# Adding threading and email subscriptions to comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've built a simple rails app with three models, Posts, Users, and Comments.

I've tried every commenting gem out there and they all have some shortfall.

So I build my own comments system.

Users can comment on Posts. Every comment is votable (using acts_as_votable gem). A users score is made up by the sum total votes they have received on their comments.

Here is what I have in my schema for the comments:

```
 create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end
```

In my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  acts_as_voter
end
```

In my post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

In my comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
end
```

In my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    post.comments.create(new_comment_params) do |comment|
      comment.user = current_user
    end
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to post_path(post)}
    end
  end


  def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.liked_by current_user

  respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @post}
    end
end


  private

  def new_comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

end
```

In my routes file:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
    member do
      put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    end
  end
  end
```

In my view:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body  %>

  <% if user_signed_in? && (current_user != comment.user) && !(current_user.voted_for? comment) %>

<%= link_to “up vote”, like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put %>

<%= comment.votes.size %>

<% else %>

<%= comment.votes.size  %></a>

<% end %>
<% end %>


<br />


<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

  <p><%= f.text_area :body, :cols => "80", :rows => "10" %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit “comment” %></p>

<% end %>
```

In the user profile views: (this shows the users score

```
<%= (@user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.inject(:+))%>
```

How do I implement threading?(at one level, I'm assuming multiple levels just makes it really messy)

How do I make the threaded comments votable?(both the parents and children) What has to be done with the routes?

How do I ad a simple email notification a user can subscribe to to receive a simple message saying that a new comment has been posted to their thread?

How do I pull the users score calculated by all votes received on comments made by the user including child comments?

Comment: please keep your question concise and ask just one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to allow comments to be commented on.  In that case, in your Comment model you will need a parent_id:integer attribute. Then add the following associations :

```
class Comment 
    ...
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment' 
    has_many :children, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
    ...
end
```

Now you have a tree structure for your comments. This allows comments of comments of comments and so on.

`if my_comment.parent.nil?` then you are at the root.  `if my_comment.children.empty?` then there are no comments on the comment.

Trees can be expensive to move through, so adding a max depth could be smart.

Answer (score 1):

How do you implement threading? (To answer one of your questions)

Make the comment-to-user association polymorphic, and then you can add a comment-to-comment association the same way.

What was the 'shortfall' you found with existing gems that prevented you doing this? (Since acts_as_commentable supports this out if the box)

Comment: How would I connect acts_as_commentable with what I currently have?

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how do implement acts as commentable with threading? I cant find how to add the reply link for comments.